# IOS login - is this code correct/secure? How can I check if the user is already logged in?

Tags: php, iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm want to make an iphone app that has a loginViewController. is this code correct and secure?

```
-(IBAction)loginPressed:(id)sender{


NSString *usr = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *psw = [[NSString alloc]init];

usr = username.text;
psw = password.text;

NSLog(@"%@",usr);
NSLog(@"%@", psw);

NSString *URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mywebsite.com/loginApp.php?user_name=%@&password=%@", usr, psw];
NSLog(@"%@", URL);
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

NSString *Result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


if ([Result isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    NSLog(@"logged in");


}else if ([Result isEqualToString:@"2"]){

    UIAlertView *WrongCredential = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Loggin failed" message:@"sorry, check again your email and password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [WrongCredential show];
}
}
```

loginApp.php

```
<?php 
 require_once 'functions/init.php';

if (isset($_GET['user_name'], $_GET['password'])){
$email = sanitize($_GET['user_name']);
$password = sanitize($_GET['password']);
$login = loginApp($email, $password);

if($login === true){
    echo json_encode(1);

                       }
    else if($login === false){
    echo json_encode(2);
    }
   }
   ?>
```

How can I check if the user has already logged in? In php I would probably set a session/cookies(?), right? How can I do it with Objective C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain one flag or variable (let say bool - isUserLoggedIn). Default value would be NO and in

```
if ([Result isEqualToString:@"1"])
{
    NSLog(@"logged in");

    isUserLoggedIn = YES;


}else if ([Result isEqualToString:@"2"]){

    UIAlertView *WrongCredential = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Loggin failed" message:@"sorry, check again your email and password" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [WrongCredential show];

    isUserLoggedIn = NO;
}
```

Now you can check anytime with this flag value (isUserLoggedIn)

Hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: This answer was related to application scope limited. If you want to persist that info even after application shutdown, then store that value using NSUserDefaults - which is better option to save single value (smallest data). You can easily get tutorials about NSUserDefaults over net.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *usr = [[NSString alloc]init];
NSString *psw = [[NSString alloc]init];

usr = username.text;
psw = password.text;
```

This piece of code create a memory leak. You don't have to alloc a string and retrieve it from label after, just replace it by :

```
NSString* usr = username.text;
NSString* psw = password.text;
```

Then, you pass the password in clear to your website. And you make this on a non-HTTPS protocole and on a GET method.

1. Encrypt the password before send to the web
2. Use a POST method to do a login
3. If possible, make your site using HTTPS protocol.

Then, in this piece of code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];
```

You make a call to the web in synchronous mode from the Main Thread. So your UI will be blocked upon the web service haven't respond. It's not a good practice. It will be better to do then in asynchronous mode.

If you're not familiar with NSURLConnection and it's asynchronous mode, I will recommend you [AFNetworking](http://www.afnetworking.com), the best REST library at this moment.

Comment: thanks for that. Can you please also suggest how to check if the uses is logged in?

Comment: You're web service need to return a cookies or an authentication keys.  When you make a ws call, if you choose the cookies, the service will check cookies to determine if you're loggedin, if you choose auth key, you pass it in http headers and you verify from your web service if the key correspond to an user and if this key is  n't rejected (e.g. too old)

Answer (score 2):

For saving username and password I will personally suggest to use Keychain as they are more safer than NSUserDefault in terms of security since Keychain stores data in encrypted form while NSUserDefault stores as plain text. You may check it out: https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController

Comment: I was just looking at the apple documentation about that. thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save user status between application launches you probably need to set value in `NSUserDefaults`.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"UserLogged"];
```

Than you can check this flag

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"UserLogged"]) {}
```

Or you can save username and password.

Also you can take a look onto [parse.com](https://parse.com) for basic singup/login functionality.